# PHP array sort using inner val

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [sort] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [sort] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [sort] => 2
    )
```

)

How do i sort it so its re-ordered using the inner 'sort' key ? ie the above would look like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [sort] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [sort] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [sort] => 3
    )
```

)

Comment: Major amounts of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sort (Damn, why is this such a hot topic lately?)

Comment: Generally PHP.net has a lot of really useful notes from users, did you look through the sort page, and if so, where did things go wrong? It's best if we can help you if we know what you have tried and what issued you're having. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: @dennis It's September 27th, I think the first round of school projects are due.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) with this comparison function:

```
function cmpBySort($a, $b) {
    return $a['sort'] - $b['sort'];
}
usort($arr, 'cmpBySort');
```

Or you use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort) with an additional array of key values for the sort order:

```
$keys = array_map(function($val) { return $val['sort']; }, $arr);
array_multisort($keys, $arr);
```

Here [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) with the [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) is used to build an array of the *sort* values that is used to sort the array values itself. The advantage of this is that there is np comparison function that needs to be called for each pair of values.

Comment: array_multisort worked for me as well. I changed $val['sort'] into ($val['sort'] * -1) to sort by descending

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
usort($array, function (array $a, array $b) { return $a["sort"] - $b["sort"]; });
```

Comment: Please delete this duplicate (and code-only) answer.  I will not serve to benefit SO readers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
uasort($array, 'compfunc');

function compfunc($a, $b)
{
    return $a['sort'] - $b['sort'];
}
```