# How to merge and sort array in php with custom or user-defined criteria?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two `array` :

```
$data1 = array( 
        (0) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 1, "index" => 1, "amount" => 50000),
        (1) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 2, "index" => 1, "amount" => 40000),
        (2) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 3, "index" => 1, "amount" => 0));  

$data2 = array( 
        (0) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 1, "index" => 1, "amount" => 30000),
        (1) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 1, "index" => 2, "amount" => 20000),
        (2) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 2, "index" => 1, "amount" => 15000),
        (3) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 2, "index" => 2, "amount" => 25000),
        (4) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 3, "index" => 1, "amount" => 0));
```

I want to merge those array into one array and the result is like this :

```
$expected = array(
         (0) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 1, "index" => 1, "amount" => 50000),
         (1) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 1, "index" => 1, "amount" => 30000),
         (2) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 1, "index" => 2, "amount" => 20000),
         (3) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 2, "index" => 1, "amount" => 40000),
         (4) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 2, "index" => 1, "amount" => 15000),
         (5) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 2, "index" => 2, "amount" => 25000));
```

I've tried to use [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) :

```
$try = array_merge_recursive($data1, $data2);
```

But the result is like this :

```
$try = array(
         (0) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 1, "index" => 1, "amount" => 50000),
         (1) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 2, "index" => 1, "amount" => 40000),
         (3) => array("level" => 1, "id" => 3, "index" => 1, "amount" => 0),
         (4) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 1, "index" => 1, "amount" => 30000),
         (5) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 1, "index" => 2, "amount" => 20000),             
         (6) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 2, "index" => 1, "amount" => 15000),
         (7) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 2, "index" => 2, "amount" => 25000),
         (8) => array("level" => 2, "id" => 3, "index" => 1, "amount" => 0));
```

I have criteria for my result :

1. Remove array where amount=0
2. Sort and order by id,level,index

I've read about [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) but i dont have any idea how to implement that function to match what i need. Is that function (uasort/usort) can solve it or any other idea? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP array sort using inner val](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804278/php-array-sort-using-inner-val)

Comment: i know there are many reference about using `usort` or `uasort` to sort an array, like i say in my question, but i still confuse how to implement with more than one criteria, so i ask that question here. Thanks to @deceze who given me clearly example for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = array_merge($data1, $data2);
$data = array_filter($data, function ($d) {
    return $d['amount'] != 0;
});
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['id'] != $b['id'])       return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
    if ($a['level'] != $b['level']) return $a['level'] - $b['level'];
    else                            return $a['index'] - $b['index'];
});
```

Note: Uses PHP 5.3+ anonymous function syntax.

Comment: great answer! Smart use of subtracting the criteria in the usort method.

Comment: Note that I may have the `$a`/`$b` arguments backwards, I always forget which return sorts ascending and descending. You may have to simply switch the values in the subtraction... :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
$finalArr = array_merge($data1,$data2);

foreach($finalArr as $key => $val) {
    if(empty($val['amount'])) {
        unset($finalArr[$key]);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
sort($finalArr);
print_r($finalArr);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works, but only for removing empty amount, still does not sort and order it by `id,level,index`. Anyway thanks for your help.